# Not sure if this is even possible, using if statement inside string sql variable

Tags: c#, sql

I have a long sql query string saved into a variable.

```
1 sSQL ="select a bunch of stuff from multiple tabled" +
2 "where conditions are met" +
3 "and other conditions are met" +
4 "order by these columns";
```

What I now need to do is to add a line between 3 and 4 that is an if statement.  Or I need to figure out some other method that doesn't involved me putting two massive sql blocks of code which is mostly redundant except for one single line.

The Code needed:

```
if (proSeries)
{
  "unique sql code to add only if proSeries is true" +
}
```

It doesn't like the block inside the string.  The only other way I can think of doing it is just copying the whole sql string into two separate variables and putting them into the if/else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have conditional logic *within* a variable declaration. You *can* however, take advantage of `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sqlText = new StringBuilder();

sqlText.AppendLine("select a bunch of stuff from multiple tabled");
...
if (proSeries)
{
  sqlText.AppendLine("unique sql code to add only if proSeries is true");
}
sqlText.AppendLine("order by these columns");

string finalText = sqlText.ToString();
```

You could easily wrap that in a function call if you will run it a lot.

Comment: @JamesWilson Glad to help. Also remember to parameterize your queries if there are any variables in those lines.

Comment: Yeah they are all parameterized.  Was a big block of sql didn't feel like bringing over the entire copied block. :)

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to having multiple conditions, I sometimes do the following, which I consider quite readable:

```
sSQL = "select a bunch of stuff from multiple tables " +
       "where conditions are met " +
       "#AND_PROSERIES_CRITERIA# " +
       "and other conditions are met " +
       "order by these columns ";

// Build all criteria strings
String sProSeriesCriteria = (proSeries) ? "and ....." : "";

// Insert all criteria
sSQL = sSQL.Replace("#AND_PROSERIES_CRITERIA#", sProSeriesCriteria);
```

Well, the effect is better with more criteria, e.g. select all orders

- from all suppliers or just certain ones AND
- for all products or just certain ones AND
- for which exist or not exist returns in another table
- ...

You get the idea. With many such optional criteria, you still write a query that is readable and then you work out the parts.

Comment: +1 This is a good alternative, especially when there are lot of things to switch around.